# Coloring rows in a table with n colors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

I know I can use *odd* and *even* to color alternating rows in a table. However, I'd like to be able to color every **third** row, so the coloring goes like *red-green-blue-red-green-blue*.

Furthermore, I'd like to make that general and use *n* colors to style every n:th row.

At the moment, I generate the table dynamically and for each iteration, I put in a class name like *modulo0*, *modulo1* etc. on every *td* tag.

Is there a better way? A more automagical one, that is.

Comment: You should provide sample output for this, it is not clear from your description

Comment: @musefan Which part is unclear? I notice that several people already answer, quite well too, so I'm not sure what to elaborate (more than already described).

Comment: At the time of posting my comment there was different answers which seemed like people had different understandings of what you wanted. It doesn't matter now

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the `:nth-child` selector with `3n`, a number can be added here to get every second starting from the start, second or third.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/vuESv/1/)

[image: Table with alternating colours]

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>R</td></tr>
    <tr><td>G</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R</td></tr>
    <tr><td>G</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr:nth-child(3n+1) td { 
    background-color:red;
}
tr:nth-child(3n+2) td { 
    background-color:green;
}
tr:nth-child(3n) td { 
    background-color:blue;
}
```

### Generally

More generally, replace `3` with the number of rows in which to change the colour.

```
tr:nth-child(2n) td { } /* every second row */
tr:nth-child(4n) td { } /* every fourth row */
tr:nth-child(10n) td { } /* every tenth row */
```

### Support

Note that [full support for CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) only comes in at IE9. If support for IE8 is essential then an alternate solution is required, like manual classes or JavaScript.

Comment: Note that this is only available from CSS3 onward and is not supported by IE8.  http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild.  PS: I didn't downvote anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `nth-child(3n+3)`. Keep in mind, that this is not a cross-browser solution. Here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hkbsg)

Answer (score 0):

May be the older way but if you don't have any problem with javascript can try below as well.

```
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function altrows(tableid,firstcolor,secondcolor,thirdcolor)
    {
          var rows = document.getElementById(tableid).getElementsByTagName("tr");

      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
      {
        i -= 1;

        for (var b=0;b<=2;b++) { 
            i +=1; 
            if(b==0){ rows[i].bgColor = firstcolor; }
            if(b==1){ rows[i].bgColor = secondcolor; }  
            if(b==2){ rows[i].bgColor = thirdcolor; }       
            }
        }
    }
    </script>


<body onLoad="altrows('tb_detail','#FF0321','#44FF03','#2103FF')">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="90%" id="tb_detail">   
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>         
</table>
</body>
```